# AngularJS/HTML/CSS - Slideshow to show different link buttons and url links

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am experimenting with creating a slideshow that has four images, for example. And the thing is I want to create a link button with its own url link for each image. But what I have done is created four link buttons that appears on the slideshow, instead of the one link button that changes along with each image, and with its own url link.

```html
{% if settings.show_block_lookbook %}
<div id="lookbook-section" class="section-full lookbook-section">

  <div class="lookbook-wrapper">
    <div class="lookbook-text">
      <div class="lookbook-container">
        <div class="container">

          <div class="lb-text">
            {% assign lbText1 = settings.block_lookbook_text_1 %}
            {% assign lbText2 = settings.block_lookbook_text_2 %}
            {% assign lbText3 = settings.block_lookbook_text_3 %}
            {% assign lbText4-1 = settings.block_lookbook_text_4_1 %}
            {% assign lbText4-2 = settings.block_lookbook_text_4_2 %}
            {% assign lbText4-3 = settings.block_lookbook_text_4_3 %}
            {% assign lbText4-4 = settings.block_lookbook_text_4_4 %}
            {% assign lbLink-1 = settings.block_lookbook_link_1 %}
            {% assign lbLink-2 = settings.block_lookbook_link_2 %}  
            {% assign lbLink-3 = settings.block_lookbook_link_3 %}  
            {% assign lbLink-4 = settings.block_lookbook_link_4 %}  

            {% if lbText1 != blank %}<h3>{{ lbText1}}</h3>{% endif %}

            <div class="bg-slider-arrows">
              <span class="button-prev no-border"></span>
              <span class="button-next no-border"></span>  
            </div>

            {% if lbText2 != blank %}<h2>{{ lbText2 }}</h2>{% endif %}

            {% if lbText3 != blank %}<p>{{ lbText3 }}</p>{% endif %}

            {% if lbText4-1 != blank %}<a href="{{ lbLink-1 }}" class="btn btn-custom btn-lb">{{ lbText4-1 }}</a>{% endif %}
            {% if lbText4-2 != blank %}<a href="{{ lbLink-2 }}" class="btn btn-custom btn-lb">{{ lbText4-2 }}</a>{% endif %}
            {% if lbText4-3 != blank %}<a href="{{ lbLink-3 }}" class="btn btn-custom btn-lb">{{ lbText4-3 }}</a>{% endif %}
            {% if lbText4-4 != blank %}<a href="{{ lbLink-4 }}" class="btn btn-custom btn-lb">{{ lbText4-4 }}</a>{% endif %}
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="lookbook-bg">
    {% for i in (1..4) %}
      {% assign newShow = 'block_lookbook_img_' | append: i %}

      {% if settings[newShow] %}
        {% assign newImage = 'block_lookbook_img_' | append: i %}

        <div class="lookbook-item">
          <img src = "{{ newImage | append: '.jpg' | asset_url}}" alt="" />
        </div>

      {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
  </div>

</div>
{% endif %}
```

I am totally lost as to what to do, as I am very very new to this. I would think I somehow need to link the images with the urls and link buttons etc, but have no idea how to code it so that each image has its own link button and url link...Any help? Any examples?

Comment: Why not use pure HTML and `ng-switch`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch It'll allow you to define four buttons and hide three of them depending on a condition.

Comment: Angular is intended to be completely disconnected from the backend, with only data transferring between the Angular app and backend server, which ever one yours might be(Django, Spring, PHP, whatever). I suggest you keep the frontend HTML-only.

Answer (score 0):

Hold on, you are not using much of angular here. I think its django or some other template with `{% if %}` .

Use something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects">
    <a href="{{ object.link }}" class="btn btn-custom btn-lb">{{object.name }}</a>
    <img src="{{ object.img_path}}" />
</div>
```

For look [try this link for `ng-repeat`](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_repeat_array)

For the functionality u need, I would recommend you to look into [cleaner approach of Carousel](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel)